# Best Practices Invoking Curl On SQL Server Table Insert?

Tags: sql, sql-server, rest, api, curl

I have a SQL Server table; every time a new row is inserted with a column that has a certain value, I want to use CURL to POST the data from that row to a RESTful Web API.

I initially thought about using a trigger on Insert for the table to call a stored procedure passing the column values are parameters which would invoke `xp_cmdshell` to use CURL.

Upon further research however people are saying that's a bad idea for all sorts of reasons from performance to data integrity. What is the best practice on how to do something like this and how exactly would you go about doing it if it were you?

Thanks. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The best option is not to do anything like this - mostly for security and performance reasons. You need to rethink your requirements and find a better solution

Comment: @marc_s Can you think of any alternative methods?  I'd like to get it as close to real-time as possible but I understand the concerns.  I won't implement it in this manner, I'm just looking for a best practice. Updating a webservice via API from inserts seems like something pretty common a lot of people would have to do.

Comment: What I'd do in this situation is exactly what @DavidBrowne has outlined in his answer: **(1)** add a "note" (preferably with all relevant info) to a table (you can do that in a trigger), and then **(2)** have a separate process (like a scheduled stored procedure, or a regularly scheduled background task on your server) that reads out that table and makes the calls to the REST API - independently and asynchronously from your web application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the fact that that a row as been inserted, but the web API has not been called.  This can either be in a status column on the table, or in a separate table maintained by your business logic (perhaps a trigger).

Then in a background process (a SQL Agent scheduled Job or somesuch) invoke the web API for each row that needs it, and update the database.